# NHibernate Filtering data best practices

Tags: nhibernate, filter, nhibernate-mapping

I have the following situation:

User logs in, opens an overview of all products, can only see a list of products where a condition is added, this condition is variable. Example: `WHERE category in ('catA', 'CatB')`

Administrator logs in, opens an overview of all products, he can see all products no filter applied.

I need to make this as dynamically as possible. My data access classes are using Generics for most of the time.

I've seen [filters](http://ayende.com/blog/3993/nhibernate-filters)  but my conditions are very variable, so i don't see this as scalable enough.

Answer (score 2):

We use NH filters for something similar, and it works fine. If no filter needs to be applied, you can omit setting any value for the filter. We use these filters for more basic stuff, filters that are applied nearly 100% of the time, fx deleted objects filters, client data segregating, etc. Not sure what scalability aspect you're looking for?

For more high level and complex filtering, we use a custom class that manipulates a repository root. Something like the following:

```
 public IQueryOver<TIn, TOut> Apply(IQueryOver<TIn, TOut> query)
 {
      return query.Where(x => ... );
 }
```

If you have an IoC container integrated with your NH usage, something like this can easily be generalized and plugged into your stack. We have these repository manipulators that do simple where clauses, and others that generate complex where clauses that reference domain logic and others that joins a second table on and filters on that.

Comment: Yeah I guess I can do something like that, store the filters in some kind of session of the user (web environment). The most filters would be on the table columns itself, not on joins.

Comment: It works well. Our enviroment is also a ASP.NET site, we use a custom `DefaultTypedFactoryComponentSelector` factory with Castle.Windsor, that along with a filter attribute class lets us source filters from our container using just a string name (from a static class containing hardcoded filter names), and which can be set by just invoking Apply, optionally setting some context data via a `void SetValue(T value)` method in the interface.

Answer (score 0):

You could save all categories in an category list and pass this list to the query. If the list is not null and contains elements you can work with the following:

```
List<string> allowedCategoriesList = new List<string>();
allowedCategoriesList.Add(...);
...
.WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.category).IsIn(allowedCategoriesList)
```

It's only important to skip this entry if you do not have any filters (so, you want to see all entries without filtering), as you will otherwise see not one single result.